# sum different values from datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this datatable:

```
SECTION    CODE  DATE        VALUE
section1    20  jul 2013    31507976.71
section1    20  nov 2013    31643256.16
section1    20  dec 2013    28788554.96
section1    20  jan 2014    32297021.88
section1    20  feb 2014    29111554.83
section1    20  mar 2014    32789670.01
section1    20  apr 2014    32045399.52
section1    20  may 2014    33420106.37
section1    20  jun 2014    31246337.7
section1    20  jul 2014    31406327.47
section2    50  apr 2013    31219430.46
section2    50  may 2013    32200204.19
section2    50  jun 2013    32348605.39
section2    50  dec 2013    33158170.04
section2    50  jan 2014    33472813.18
section2    50  feb 2014    30875748.12
section2    50  mar 2014    34655429.31
section2    50  apr 2014    31894634.74
section2    50  may 2014    29467627.18
section2    50  jun 2014    31224988.16
section2    50  jul 2014    59455468.22
section3    20  apr 2013    29467627.18
section3    20  nov 2013    28230480.06
section3    20  dec 2013    27273436.72
section3    20  jan 2014    27074471.34
section3    20  may 2014    31396504.33
section3    20  jun 2014    29528727.08
section3    20  jul 2014    29630946.19
```

I want to get a total by a specific code for each period.
ex. for code 20 it will count each section that has code 20 in second column and sum by each period. 
I should get a list like this:

```
 Period      Code: 20
apr 2013    29467627.18
apr 2014    32045399.52
dec 2013    56061991.68
feb 2014    29111554.83
jan 2014    59371493.22
jul 2013    31507976.71
jul 2014    61037273.66
jun 2013    0
jun 2014    60775064.78
mar 2014    32789670.01
may 2013    0
may 2014    64816610.7
nov 2013    59873736.22
```

This is what I tried, but I get only zero values:

```
string code="20";
       List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
            List<string> period = new List<string>();           
            List<decimal> value = new List<decimal>();  
            decimal nr=0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                if (dr[1].ToString().Equals(code))
                    period.Add(dr[2].ToString());
            }
        List<string>period2= period.Distinct().ToList();
            foreach (string p in period2) value.Add(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < period2.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                { if (period2[i].Equals(dr[2].ToString()))
                        nr += Convert.ToDecimal(dr[3].ToString());
                }
                value[i] = nr;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < period2.Count; i++)
            {
                data.Add(new string[] {period2[i], value[i].ToString()});
            }
```

Comment: I have a gut feeling you need to use == instead of Equals

Comment: I'm not sure yet, why you are gettign zero, but you should reset for `nr` variable everytime before you iterate over the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do the trick for you to Select all Rows where code is 20 and date is greater than Apr / 2013.

```
List<DataRow> result = urDataTable.Select("CODE == 20 AND DATE > #1/4/2013#");
foreach (DataRow row in result)
{
    //do
}
```

if `CODE` is non-numeric care to put `20` like `'20'`

Comment: the period is random, could be less than apr 2013. I put only a little part of datatable. but I need to get for a code all periods that exist in my datatable, even for a period that code has zero value.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your results by Date and Code.
Then you can filter them by code, to get values you want.

I would recommend mapping your results to a model first, so it would be easier to read, than by referencing string array by indexes.

Something like this:

```
public class SectionModel
{
    public string SectionId { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

var list = dt.Rows.Select(d => new SectionModel
            {
                SectionId = d[0],
                Code = Convert.ToInt32(d[1]),
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime(d[2]),
                Value = Convert.ToDecimal(d[3])
            });

            var results = list.GroupBy(row => new {row.Date, row.Code}, (key, rows) => new
            {
                period = key.Date,
                code = key.Code,
                value = rows.Sum(r => r.Value)
            })
                .Where(r => r.code == codeParameter)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information you want by making use of `GroupBy` like this:

```
var aggregatedItems = items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Code, x.Period })
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Code = g.Key.Code,
                Period = g.Key.Period,
                Value = g.Sum(y => y.Value)
            });
```

After that you can access them like this (ordering is optional):

```
foreach (var item in aggregatedItems.OrderBy(x=>x.Code).ThenBy(x=>x.Period))
{
    Console.WriteLine($@"Code:{item.Code}\t\tPeriod:{item.Period}\tSum:{item.Value}");
}
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GQoMmz).